# System.ObjectDisposedException C# Ssh project

Tags: c#, ssh, lib

I have triying to send ssh commands to my CPU using Renci and sshnet libraries by clicking two buttons. First button, it works fine but when i clicked the second, it says

> 'System.ObjectDisposedException'

for client At those rows.

```
client.Connect();
shCommand cmd3 = client.RunCommand("ls -la checkEth*");
```

Could anyone help?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SshClient client = new SshClient("192.168.1.5", "deneme", "deneme");
    int milliseconds;
    
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Button 1 clicked");
        using (client)
        {
            milliseconds = 200;
            Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);
           
            
                client.Connect();
            SshCommand cmd = client.RunCommand("ls > checkEth.txt");
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("chechethYapildi 1: " + cmd.Result);
                
                Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);
                SshCommand cmd2 = client.RunCommand("ls -la checkEth*");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("com 1:" + cmd2.Result);
            textBox1.Text = (cmd2.Result);

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("cevapgelecek");
            
            //client.Dispose();
               
        }
        client.Dispose();

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (client)
        {
            client.Connect();
            SshCommand cmd3 = client.RunCommand("ls -la checkEth*");
            textBox1.Text = (cmd3.Result);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ikinci butona basıldı");
        }
            

        


    }
}
```

Comment: The first command you are writing the output to a file and NOT checking the results.   The second command you a piping the output to standardoutput.  Then getting an error when reading results with : textBox1.Text = (cmd2.Result);  Why do you have parenthesis around cmd2.Result?  Is cmd2.Result a text string?

Comment: Yes, cmd2.Result is a text string.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. When I am using "using(client)", I dispose the client. Because of disposing, button2_Click won't be able to connect the same client. My new code is below.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SshClient client = new SshClient("192.168.1.5", "deneme", "deneme");
    int milliseconds;
    
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Button 1 clicked");
        
            milliseconds = 200;
            Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);
           
            
                client.Connect();
            SshCommand cmd = client.RunCommand("ls > checkEth.txt");
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("chechethYapildi 1: " + cmd.Result);
                
                Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);
                SshCommand cmd2 = client.RunCommand("ls -la checkEth*");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("com 1:" + cmd2.Result);
            textBox1.Text = (cmd2.Result);

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("cevapgelecek");
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            SshCommand cmd3 = client.RunCommand("ls -la checkEth*");
            textBox1.Text = (cmd3.Result);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ikinci butona basıldı");
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You're reusing the same `client` object in both button event methods. Each method contains a using statement, which will cause `Dispose` method to be called when control leaves the using block. A client that has already been disposed cannot be reused.

You need to either dispose the client elsewhere, or create a new client in each event handler, and dispose it as you do now.